# Step-by-step solution of a system of symbolic equations - Call Wolfram Alpha in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, education

I'm trying to get a step-by-step solution of a system of symbolic equations:

```
WolframAlpha["{-R3*IR3=Z*I2+VWE2,VIN/R4=IR3+IC3,ZC3*IC3+Z*I3+Z*I1+\
VWE1=0,I3=I1+I2,-VWE2-Z*I2+Z*I1+VWE1=0},{IR3,I1,I2,I3,IC3}", 
PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

The above code does not work; instead if I have a system of numeric equations, it works:

```
WolframAlpha["x+y+z=1,x+3y-5z=3,14y-5z=0", 
 PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}]
```

The problem is how specify the unknowns.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WolframAlpha appears to be pretty consistently confused by multicharacter variable names, and sometimes even by single character names.

This appears to work

```
WolframAlpha["solve {-a*b=Z*c+d,e/f=b+g,h*g+Z*i+Z*j+k=0,i=j+c,-d-Z*c+Z*j+k=0} for {b,j,c,i,g}"]
```

but doesn't include your `PodStates` which you try to put back in and get that correct.

Comment: Hello @Bill, I need step-by-step solution; run my second code please.

Comment: I understand what you want/need. I tried over and over and over and over to get "Podstates" to work and I simply failed. I tried your code, I tried other SE examples, I simply failed. But I did show you how to get WolframAlpha to understand and solve your system. And I left it up to you to insert your "Podstates" and get it working, apparently you are better at that than I am. So I hope you are able to complete that last step.

Comment: Hello @Bill, finally I found the solution also thanks to your reply: WolframAlpha["{-a*b=Z*c+d,e/f=b+g,h*g+Z*i+Z*j+k=0,i=j+c,-d-Z*c+Z*j+k=\
0} for {b,j,c,i,g}", PodStates -> {"Solution__Step-by-step solution"}]